# how to use ActiveX in PHP?

Tags: php, activex

What i should do to use **ActiveX** on **php**?

I have a few dll, that implements connection to db. But i don't know, how to use them on php.
I understand, that i can't write smt like require('mylib.dll'), but what should i do?

So, the first question is:
how to "include" dll in php code?

And the second is:
How use ActiveX objects in code?

i'll expect smt like this:

```
$obj = new ActiveXObject("MyActiveX.MyConnection");
```

Comment: What *exactly* is it that you want to do?

Comment: I want to connect to berkliDB, via ActiveX. Like in this doc: http://docs.gurtam.com/en/hosting/activex/install/start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is possible using the [COM Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php).

I don't know if it works for your specific ActiveX-Controls since they have to implement `IDispatch` otherwise the "dynamic" access to the methods won't work. And as far as I know you can't import a typelib in PHP.

Comment: May be i wrong, but... isn't this fucntion load and register type library: [com_load_typelib](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.com-load-typelib.php)

Comment: Yes, you can import the constants in the typelib (thats what it does according to the description), but it won't get you very far if you try to actually call methods of an object which does not implement `IDispatch` because otherwise you have to dynamically access the objects [vtbl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) and call the function - that could work somehow but I don't think the COM functions go that far (haven't tested it though). If you have to access a non IDisptach-object you have to write a PHP extension in c++ which calls the methods of the object.