# where to put ActiveX dll for use in php

Tags: php, com, cpanel

I have activex dll com component that I have to use in my PHP.

I have windows based server, I have access to it only via CPanel.

The question is - HOW TO Properly register dll with cpanel? Is it possible?

I do not have idea how and where should I put my dll file, so I can use it in PHP (using COM).

Probably, this is dummy question, but I have not really found anything in google. All suggestions are related to windows server and system32 folder etc., but what about remote access via cpanel? If it is my own windows workstation, I know how to register it.

This is custom dll file. It is not written in PHP.

Comment: you can stuff it anywhere you want. as long as it's properly registered with windows so that Windows knows where to find it when you invoke it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316694/how-to-use-activex-in-a

Comment: It is not duplicate, cause I do not need help of how to use it via PHP. I do not know how to properly register it if I have remote access to cpanel only?

Comment: Is this some custom .dll? Not php module?

Comment: It is custom dll, not php module. Written in VB or something like that.

Comment: @renathy: Cpanel on it's own does not allow you to register the .dll file, you need access to the system and execute a command there. Where to put the file depends on the concrete operating system and which architecture your .dll supports, like if it is a 32 or 64 bit file. So you need shell access with administrative privileges. And then you install / register the file as if this is a normal windows operating system. If you've got more questions, contact the vendor of CPanel for your further support options.

Comment: If a *.dll is how windows packs a *.so file, one could add the link library to the php.ini as an extension. Is the new file a valid extension? As for where to put your *dll, it will need to be in  the shared libs directory (normally compiled to file://c:/windows/system32, its controllable via 'extension_dir').

Do you have access to the config file?

Comment: @OwenBeresford: ActiveXDLL aren't working as PHP extensions. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

As already commented above yesterday, Cpanel on it's own does not allow you to register the .dll file, you need access to the system and execute a command there. Where to put the file depends on the concrete operating system and which architecture your .dll supports, like if it is a 32 or 64 bit file.

So you need shell access with administrative privileges. And then you install / register the file as if this is a normal windows operating system.

This is most certainly not the answer you're looking for, but this is how it is. If you've got more questions, contact the vendor of the CPanel you're using (the hoster) for your further support options. Also the manufacturer of CPanel might have some more hints when you contact their support. However the general rules from above apply. Access the server with administrative privileges and register the .dll. After registering it, you can just use it via [PHP COM extension](http://www.php.net/book.com.php).

Comment: What if I use another hosting server, are there any that supports it? Hostgator with Parallels Panel?

Comment: @renathy: If that then I'd say. Why not contacting your current hosting provider asking for support in this issue? If you choose a new hosting provider you should *clarify your issue* before contracting, so the hoster meets your requirements. If this is your windows server, you must get administrative privileges somehow otherwise it's managed and then support should help you.

Comment: It is because I am developer and I do not have direct contacts with hosting providers, I am giving this information to client, but I should give him precise information (but I am not familiar with all this staff).

Comment: Well, tell your client your requirements. And then let it go. Unless your client can provide a system that matches your requirements, tell your client there is nothing more to talk. Those are your requirements and as such are ***requirements*** therefore there is not much more to say or to change about. So the important part with the communication problem you outline here, is that you must say it is a so called *Requirement* which - by the meaning of the word - has nothing more to add. Just tell them you need that COM server on that server under this name.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you need access to a command prompt to register an ActiveX control.

To clarify: an ActiveX dll (COM server) is **not** loaded like a normal code .dll. A normal code .dll is loaded by name and so it is important to place a normal dll somewhere in the PATH (or to update the PATH to include the dll's location).

None of this is required for an ActiveX control. As others have said, you can put the ActiveX dll anywhere. What *is* required, is for the ActiveX control to be registered with the system. You do this from the command line using the [Regsvr32](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regsvr32.mspx?mfr=true) command. From the directory containing your ocx/dll enter the following at the command prompt:

```
Regsvr32 /s YOUR.OCX
```